# How to force mac to use ssh dsa key?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, openssh

When I try to log on ssh in my linux server from OSX, I force it to use a dsa key with the ssh config file. However, before connecting with the dsa key, it tries to connect with a rsa key (which doesn't exist). This is annoying because my ssh server allows only one connection attempt. 
Is there a fix for that, or is my config wrong ?

~/.ssh/config.txt :

> `Host homessh
>       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
>       HostName 192.168.1.1
>       Port 22
>       User user`

ssh logs (with ssh -v)

> `MacBook:.ssh User$ ssh homessh -v
>   OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/User/.ssh/config
>   debug1: /Users/User/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for homessh
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
>   debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
>   debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
>   debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
>   debug1: Connection established.
>   debug1: identity file /Users/User/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>   debug1: identity file /Users/User/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
>   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7
>   debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7 pat OpenSSH*
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
>   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
>   debug1: Server host key: DSA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>   debug1: Host '[192.168.1.1]:22' is known and matches the DSA host key.
>   debug1: Found key in /Users/User/.ssh/known_hosts:17
>   debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>   debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>   debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa
>   Received disconnect from 192.168.1.1: 2: Too many authentication failures for user from 192.168.1.2 port 55565 ssh2`

Comment: If you know that you want use special identity, `IdentitiesOnly` option is your friend, but it looks like it doesn't work for you from log. Maybe more verbose log would help. How did you create your key and how did you copy it to remote host?

Comment: Well, I didn't do anything at all and it worked by its own. I have a right log now : it uses the dsa key at first. That's pretty weird. Maybe my mac went to sleep and it killed some remaining ssh process / reloaded a part of the config file. Thank you anyway !

Comment: Please, mark your answer as a solution. This question will not help anybody, but at least it will be marked as solved and other people will not waste their time investigating it once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved for no reason, maybe the config file was reloaded when my mac went to sleep. 
Thank you.

Comment: @Ramhound This **is** an answer from the OP.